# Modifying the GET request response in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a private field feature using django.I saved the private fields in django MutliSelectField.After this is done  now a differnt API is used to fetch the data.Before sending the response I need to eliminate the fields specified in MultiSelectField.In the serializer we can use create and update method for modifying the results of a POST, PUT and PATCH requests. Similarly is there any method that I can override so as to remove the items specified in the django MultiSelectField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to achieve it. In the serializer there is a method called `to_representation`. overriding it gives the ability to modify the response data just before it is sent.